# ImageMagick compare images with API?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have the following code:

```
MagickWand *wand = NewMagickWand();
char* cmdargs[] = {
    "compare",
    "receipt-expected.png",
    "-metric",
    "psnr",
    "difference.png",
    "difference2.png",
    NULL
};
int argcount = 6;
// Allocate memory for MagickCommand
ImageInfo * info = AcquireImageInfo();
ExceptionInfo* e = AcquireExceptionInfo();
// Execute command
char *metadata = NULL;
MagickBooleanType status = MagickCommandGenesis(info, CompareImageCommand, argcount, cmdargs, &metadata, e);
```

`status` is 0, which I assume it working because it has no error and the command works correctly in the CLI.

How do I get the metric it has produced? `meta` is `NULL`.

```
$ compare receipt-expected.png -metric psnr difference.png  difference2.png
15.4169
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would access the API directly, rather than attempting to call a new ImageMagick process as a subprocess.

```c
MagickWand * alpha, * beta, * result;
// ... Allocated & Init `alpha' & `beta'
double metric;
result = MagickCompareImages(alpha,
                             beta,
                             PeakSignalToNoiseRatioMetric,
                             &metric);
printf("psnr = %f\n", metric);
```

> How do I get the metric it has produced?

You can not, as `metadata` is intended to hold additional IO information in a heap. In this instance, any information written to `char ** metadata` will be destroyed immediately after the internal command writes to standard output. See [here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/mogrify.c#L182) for reference.

Comment: Is metric percent difference?